# Update registry value delimited/separated by commas

Tags: powershell, registry

I have a working script to update a registry key value, I'm curious to know if there is a better/faster/easier/shorter way to do it.  What are some other ways to do it?

```
$array = @()    
$RegKey = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" | select AppInit_DLLs | % {$_.AppInit_DLLs -split ","}
foreach ($value in $RegKey)
{
    if ($value -notmatch "mfaphook64.dll")
    {
        $array+= $value        
    }
    if ($value -match "mfaphook64.dll")
    {
        $value = "mfaphook64.dll"
        $array+= $value
    }
} 
$array = $array -join ","    
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" -Name AppInit_DLLs -Value $array -Force
```

Value Before:

```
C:\test path\mfaphook64.dll,test.dll
```

Value After:

```
mfaphook64.dll,test.dll
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the two `if` statements? They appear to be doing the exact thing...

Comment: This first if statement adds the value to my array if it does not contain my search string.  The second if statement replaces the sub-string with a new value, and adds it to the array.  This way I can replace the path while keeping all other sub-strings.

Comment: Ah, with you. Makes sense, I wasn't paying enough attention to the use of `-match`

Comment: Made the same mistake at first @Arco444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$AppInitdlls = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" | Select-Object -expand AppInit_DLLs 
$AppInitdlls = $AppInitdlls -replace "(.*,)?.+?mfaphook64\.dll(,.*)?",'$1mfaphook64.dll$2'
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" -Name AppInit_DLLs -Value $AppInitdlls -Force
```

There should be no need to expand this into an array if you are just looking to manipulate the string mfaphook64.dll. A simple `-replace` should be able to handle that.

If you are looking to replace the path what you are currently doing might be easier to do however, unless someone beats me to it, a regex solution will be faster.

**Regex Breakdown**: `(.*,)?.+?mfaphook64\.dll(,.*)?`

- `(.*,)?` If there is something before the path of the dll it is collected here.
- `.+?mfaphook64\.dll` would match whatever the path was. All the characters after that comma up until the "dll" characters.
- `(,.*)?` If there is something after the path of the dll it is collected here.
- The replace takes everything that was captured before (capture in `$1`) and after (capture in `$2`) and puts the string "mfaphook64.dll" in between.

Live example can be found at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sO6cR3/1)

Comment: The value can contain a path to the DLL, it may not be the same place every time.  I am searching for just the DLL to delete the full path.  A literal replace won't work for my needs.

Comment: @user3208164 OH ok... just need to update the replace then. Updated to reflect post edit.

Comment: need to account if it is in the beginning or end of string. This wont work right now.

Comment: I just tested and I got this error:  The regular expression pattern C:\test path\mfaphook64.dll,test.dll is not valid.

Comment: @user3208164 Copy and paste typo. Try again please. Forgive my last comment if you read it.

Comment: After changing the second line to this it worked!  $AppInitdlls = $AppInitdlls -replace "(.*,)?.+?mfaphook64\.dll(,.*)?",'$1mfaphook64.dll$2'